# Google maps api in backbone view, not displaying zoom and marker icons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js

I am creating a backbone view where I want to show a map using the Javascript api for Google Maps.

In my html file I have this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 300px; float:left"></div>
```

And in the backbone view I have the following:

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: $('#map'),

  initialize: function() {

  var defaultSettings = { date:'01/12/2016', time: '10:00', 
                       lat:'40.72815832561118', lng: '-73.99564975565187'   };

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(defaultSettings.lat, defaultSettings.lng);

  var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Current Position"
    });

  }
});
```

When I try and load the map, I actually get it on the exact position I want, however the icons for zoom and marker are not showing.

[image]

If i wait for a long time, the zoom icons show up however the marker never appears. What could be the problem?

Comment: Your code works fine for me (https://jsfiddle.net/qxwxw1b1/) are you behind a firewall or something similar which is causing the image resources to load slowly? The zoom controls come from: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl.png

Comment: I have used the same code only with raw javascript, not backbone, and it works as expected. Loads normally.

Comment: Backbone itself doesn't interfere with the DOM, so if you can't recreate your issue in a JSFiddle, then it's probably something else that's causing the problem.